# How does the shell translate * into a list of files/dirs?

Tags: linux, bash

When I type `ls *` what goes on behind the scenes in the shell?

What system calls are made?

How does the shell translate * into a list of files and directories?

Comment: Try `strace ls *`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

Comment: @Matthieu, that won't help; the glob is done before `ls` (or `strace`) is started.

Comment: @BenVisser, to be on topic here, a question has to be about a specific problem that you actually face. Curiosity-based questions are out of scope.

Comment: @Matthieu You probably meant `strace bash -c 'ls *'`. However, I would recommend `strace bash -c 'printf %s\\n *'` first, and (if necessary) `ls` afterwards to make it easier to understand what `*` does and what `ls` does.

Comment: The real problem with this question is that its scope is effectively unbounded. The amount of detail one could go into (for each of the many shell implementations) is effectively unlimited. ("In shell X version Y, the recursive function Z is called for each path element in a glob expression, and is responsible for in turn calling A or B depending on whether that individual path element can be itself interpreted as a glob expression, a determination made by function C...")

Answer (score 3):

The only involved *syscalls* are `opendir` and `readdir` (or whatever equivalents your local operating system provides). Actual pattern matching does not require syscall/kernel support, and is done in userland.

That said, you may find the standard C library function `fnmatch` -- which evaluates whether a string matches a glob-style pattern of interest.

That said, bash does not use that function call, but implements globbing internally.

Answer (score 2):

> If `ls *` is a shell command line, then the shell will expand that `*`
> according to the corresponding shell's globbing (also referred to as
> Filename Generation or Filename Expansion) rules.
>
> While different shells support different globbing operators, most of
> them agree on the simplest one `*`. `*` as a pattern means any number
> of characters, so `*` as a glob will expand to the list of files in
> the current directories that match that pattern. There's an exception
> however that a leading dot (.) character in a file name has to be
> matched explicitly, so `*` actually expands to the list of files and
> directories not starting with . (in lexicographical order).

check the original post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls